# Converting ros::Time to C++ string

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can we convert the result of `ros::Time::now()` into `std::string`, given that `std::string to_string (*)` in C++11 doesn't support this conversion ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337115/converting-ros::time-to-c++-string/) by [zlg9](https://answers.ros.org/users/46453/zlg9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-07-14**:
Answer to convert to a formatted date time string using `boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string` #q251966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want to use the `ros::Time::now().toSec()` result, which is a double.

http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1TimeBase.html#ab63e3c9f57032143d4eeac4a7ac272a5

Then you can convert that double to a string with `std::string to_string`.

You could use `strftime` to convert the double to many different string formats as well.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2019-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zlg9](https://answers.ros.org/users/46453/zlg9/) on 2019-11-08**:
Yes, that's what I needed. Thanks